# Win32: How can i set the color of windows Title, Scrollbar etc.?

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi

I am updating a GUI of a Win32 Application in white text on black background. Thats simple for my content. But how can i change also the color of my child windows (Titlebar, Scrollbar etc.). i Know there is  `WM_CTLCOLORDLG` to set the color of Dialogs. I also know there is `WM_NCPAINT`, but that would leave all painting (i.e of Scrollbars) to me. All i want, is to set colors of my choice.

Comment: The Win32 API heavily favors giving the user the colors that she selected when she chose her preferred theme with the Display control panel applet.  Yes, you can do your own painting to force your color choice.

Comment: The caption (titlebar) is not a child window; it's part of the non-client (the `NC` in `WM_NCPAINT`) area of your window.

Comment: I am talking about child windows having a own titlebar. The application creates some of those. Their black on gray title conflicts with the rest of the app which now is white on black.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SetSysColors() to change the colour for window captions, borders, etc. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724940(VS.85).aspx). However this will change the colour for all windows, not just yours, so it is at the least an unfriendly thing to do.

One option is to use SetSysColors() to change the active window caption colour when your application has focus and to reset it to the defaults when it loses focus. But I'd say that's klunky and not really in keeping with good practice (suppose your application crashes? and there might be some flickering).

WM_NCPAINT is there so that you can do things like this. It is a bit of a pain, but maybe that's to discourage you from creating non-standard windows... ;-)

Comment: Changing system-wide settings temporarily like that is a very, very bad practice.

Comment: Which is what I said. WM_NCPAINT is the way to go -- or go back to your designer and ask him to justify this decision.

Answer (score 1):

Hook GetSysColor() (Using something like Microsoft Detours)