# How do I set text color for the Caption of an MDI app using Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, win32gui

[image]

I am stuck with MFC/WIN32 ( no .NET or anything managed )

Comment: That's a non-client area, and as such is painted by the system using the current user theme. If you want to change it you might have to paint the entire area yourself by trapping WM_NCPAINT.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056774/win32-how-can-i-set-the-color-of-windows-title-scrollbar-etc

Comment: Read source code for open source projects that do this, e.g. open source browsers

Comment: You can aso use themes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/using-visual-styles

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have looked at Chrome and Firefox source code for 3 days, I couldn't figure out what they do exactly. They use `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea`, that much is apparent, but the rest is their own weird method. @Michael Themes are not used in title bar since with Windows Vista. There are no standard APIs for duplicating the title bar, I think.

Comment: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dwm/customframe)